# Check if void methods were called

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm stuck in my first jUnit Test with Mockito.

I must test a method, which takes an ArrayList as parameter. In this method, there will be another class called which runs Runtimes execution. So I need to mock the class with the Runtime executions, because they want fail on Jenkins (becuase Jenkins runs on Linux).

First the two classes:
`HandleInformation testClass;` the class which will be testet
`XFDHandler test;` the interface with the Runtime executions, the class is called XFDHandlerProd

So first I mock the Runtime-Class:

```
test = Mockito.mock(XFDHandlerProd.class);
```

The four methods are all *void*-methods, so the method itself shouldn't do anything when I understand the [official doc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing%28%29) correctly:

> Beware that void methods on mocks do nothing by default!

So then I'll do my first test:

```
@Test
public void testNullList() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<Info> nullArray = new ArrayList<Info>();

    testClass.handleInformation(nullArray);
    Mockito.verify(test, Mockito.times(1)).turnOnBlue();
}
```

When I send an empty List to the testClass, it should be called the void-method of the Runtime-Class `turnOnBlue();`. And as far as I know, with the `verify` method I can check if the method was really called.

But when I now run the test, I'll get the following error:

> Wanted but not invoked: xFDHandlerProd.turnOnBlue();
>   -> at com.example.example.business.HandleInformationTest.testNullList(HandleInformationTest.java:44)
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

And the line #44 is the line with `Mockito.verfiy()`

Now I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

---

**Thought**
Is the communication zero becuase I use in the `HandleInformation` class I use another instance of the `XFDHandler`, and so Mockito can't see any activity?
If it so, how I'm able to use in the test the Mockito Class without changing any method in the `HandleInformation` class?

Comment: Are you injecting/setting the 'test' instance in the 'testClass'? Your thought is probably right as you need to inject the created mock for XFDHandler into the HandleInformation class. How is your HandleInformation class instantiated?

Comment: Can you add code showing how you are setting up the `testClass` object please?

Comment: Um, that's not a null array, that's an _empty_ array, there's a difference.  Not really your problem though (or at least, I doubt it).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Good point. It doesn't matter if it's empty or null, but the name is really misspelling. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to pass the colaborator as a parameter. This means that you need something like this:

```
XFDHandler test = Mockito.mock(XFDHandlerProd.class);
HandleInformation testClass = new HandleInformation(test);
```

Then your test would work.

Btw, I would remove Mockito.times(1) because its the default behaviour

Comment: Exactly that. Thanks a lot. 
And yes, I just saw it in the doc, I can remove it. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should inject your mocked object into your object under test using setter or constructor or just pass as a method parameter so that mockito could understand when object you are testing calls mocked object methods